# Joining Two Data-sets in PowerPivot by Month

Tags: join, relationship, powerpivot

I've got 2 different data sets, revenue and contracts sold, that I need to join based off of year and month in PowerPivot so when I use my slicers, they'll filter accordingly. I know part of this will involve coming up with some temp tables for year and month but I can't get those to work. In the contracts sold table, there is an actual date column which I'm then using to format the year/month in "MM-MMM" format:

[image]

However, the revenue comes in only as a YYYYMM format:

[image]

So the solution would have to take into account this aspect as well. It's been a while since I've dealt with PowerPivot and I recall the PowerPivotPro or Kasep de Jonge's site containing something about linking tables based off of common month but I can't find those pages anymore. If anyone could point me in the right direction or give me some insight, it'd be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Excel 2010 with PowerPivot version 11.0.3000.0.

Thanks,

Joshua

Answer (score 0):

**Joshua**, I think the solution can be quite simple:

1. In the *contracts sold* table, create a new **calculated column** (a new column within a powerpivot window) that would give you the same date format as is in the *revenue* table (YYYYMM).
2. Use [Create Time Dimension](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/create-time-dimension-WA103994479.aspx) app in Excel 2013 -- this app creates a date-table with unique dates which makes everything much easier. As with the other table, create a new **calculated column** with the same format (YYYYMM).
3. Make a relationship between those tables -- the date table will be linked to revenue as well as contracts.
4. Created required measures (like sums of revenue, number of contracts etc.).
5. Place a new pivot table - rows will probably be date-based (YYYYMM), with measures coming from both tables it should be easy to create a report that you need.